# ELMAH doesn't show error code line number (Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

I received many email generated by ELMAH.  They only show the stack trace .Net Framework code, but none of them is my code.  Thus I have no idea where the bug is.  How do I configure ELMAH to show the line of my code where the error occurred?  The web.config has

```xml
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.5.2">
```

Here is the email generated by ELMAH

```
System.Web.HttpException: Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.
Generated: Tue, 21 Jun 2016 23:23:03 GMT

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Server Variables 
Name    Value
ALL_HTTP    removed
ALL_RAW removed
APPL_MD_PATH    /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/CMT
APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH  D:\webs\mydomain\CMT\
AUTH_TYPE   NTLM
AUTH_USER   domain\username
AUTH_PASSWORD   *****
LOGON_USER  domain\username
REMOTE_USER domain\username
CERT_COOKIE  
CERT_FLAGS   
CERT_ISSUER  
CERT_KEYSIZE    256
CERT_SECRETKEYSIZE  2048
CERT_SERIALNUMBER    
CERT_SERVER_ISSUER  removed
CERT_SERVER_SUBJECT removed
CERT_SUBJECT     
CONTENT_LENGTH  0
CONTENT_TYPE     
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1
HTTPS   on
HTTPS_KEYSIZE   256
HTTPS_SECRETKEYSIZE 2048
HTTPS_SERVER_ISSUER removed
HTTPS_SERVER_SUBJECT    removed
INSTANCE_ID 2
INSTANCE_META_PATH  /LM/W3SVC/2
LOCAL_ADDR  removed
PATH_INFO   /cmt/
PATH_TRANSLATED D:\webs\mydomain\CMT\
QUERY_STRING     
REMOTE_ADDR removed
REMOTE_HOST removed
REMOTE_PORT 54590
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
SCRIPT_NAME /cmt/
SERVER_NAME removed
SERVER_PORT 443
SERVER_PORT_SECURE  1
SERVER_PROTOCOL HTTP/1.1
SERVER_SOFTWARE Microsoft-IIS/8.5
URL /cmt/
HTTP_CONNECTION Keep-Alive
HTTP_ACCEPT */*
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    gzip, deflate, peerdist
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    en-US 
HTTP_AUTHORIZATION  removed
NTLM HTTP_COOKIE    removed
HTTP_HOST   removed
HTTP_USER_AGENT Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
HTTP_DNT    1
HTTP_X_P2P_PEERDIST Version=1.0
Powered by ELMAH, version 1.2.14706.955. Copyright (c) 2004, Atif Aziz. All rights reserved. Licensed under Apache License, Version 2.0.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to identify the exact problem, when we cannot see your controller handling the failing request. What it looks like to me is, that your action contains some async code, which actually run after returning from the request.

You can hack this by surrounding your code in try-catch and using the ErrorSignal class from ELMAH to log the actual error thrown inside the action. But again, providing us with more code, would make it much easier to help.